# Retrieve model with its recursive relationship in a single model

Tags: laravel, model, eloquent, laravel-5

I have two Models, Account and Contractor. An account(user) can be a contractor so I created a recursive relationship. The Contractor model look like this.

```
class Contractor extends Model
{
    protected $table = "contractors";

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo("\App\Account", "user_id", "id");
    }

}
```

Having in mind that an account has the next fields

**Account**

- id
- passwd
- name

I would like to retrieve contractors with its fields and the user fields merged just as if they where the same, like that:

**Contractor**

- id
- passwd
- name
- contractor_type

I don't want to do:

```
\App\Contractor::with('user')->first();
```

I would like to retrieve all fields with

```
\App\Contractor::first()
```

is possible to achieve that by overriding some method or in some tricky way?

Comment: it's not possible , with is require for relation

Comment: You need a [join](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#joins) statement to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

You need a join statement to achieve this. Something along these lines (there is inner, left and right join, I'm not sure which one suits you best).

```
$contractor = \App\Contractor::join('users', 'contractors.user_id', '=', 'accounts.id')
    ->select('accounts.id', 'contractors.user_id', 'accounts.id', 'accounts.passwd', 'accounts.name', 'contractors.contractor_type')
    ->first();
```

I assumed table names "accounts" and "contractors".

Answer (score 1):

I think your query like:

```
$rsltContractors = \App\Contractor::selectRaw('accounts.id', 'accounts.passwd', 'accounts.name','contractors.id','contractors.user_id','contractors.name','contractors.contractor_type')
             ->join('accounts', 'accounts.id', '=', 'contractors.user_id')->first();
```

Hope this work for you!